# JSONP getting data issue

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp

I have a really weird issue , I'm trying to get my data from cross domain address but when I use JSONP I don't get any errors in console but also there is no data returned here is my code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://djordjepetrovic.rs/tweets.json",
    crossDomain:true,
    type:'get',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {    
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

There is and url for the json file so if you know how to fix this, please let me know.

Comment: I tried your code in the Chrome console and it worked fine.

Comment: I do the same thing and I get "Object {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, getResponseHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}" but there is no data for tweets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API you are trying to consume doesn't seem to support JSONP. Read the documentation whether this is the case and if it supports what is the name of the parameter to set the JSONP callback in the response. Right now this endpoint returns JSON, not JSONP. That's why you cannot consume it with an AJAX call.

Comment: I created this JSON file and posted on my website , what should I change to make it work ?

Comment: If the JSON file is hosted on your domain you should remove the `crossDomain: true` property, use a relative `url: "/tweets.json"` and set the `dataType:'json'`.